# Why does the input event run twice and show the previous value in Firefox for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, firefox-android

I am trying to remove invalid characters and convert them to uppercase;

If you run the code on latest Firefox for Android, the input event will be fired twice and the input value will be duplicated.

But if you remove any manipulations (toUpperCase or replace), then the problem disappears.

**Test case one (with the problem)**

```js
var input = document.getElementById("a");
input.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
    //input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
  //input.value = input.value.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi);
  input.value = input.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, '');

  console.log("event");
});
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text">
```

**Test case two (without the problem)**

```js
var input = document.getElementById("a");
input.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
    //input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, '');
  //input.value = input.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, '');

  console.log("event");
});
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text">
```

What is the reason of the behavior and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**:
Screenshot for clarity. I entered "ABC"
[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT 2:**
It looks like this code is causing a problem on apple mobile devices - when clicking on keyboard hints, these hints are not used.
A temporary solution is to use filtering (replace) at the input event, and use uppercase  - through the focusout or via css (text-transform: uppercase) and further transformation on the server

Comment: @Liam I don't why, but some Firefox for Android show the error and some work correctly.

Comment: Don't you think that Firefox for Android is right and other browser aren't. After all when you do `input.value = input.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, '');` it is normal that the `input` event would be trigger. If this is the origine of your problem, maybe you could use the `isTrusted` property of the event.

Comment: @CedricCholley Your argument looks logical, but why then doesn't it work exactly the same when `input.value = input.value.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi);`?

Comment: Good point. I don't believe it is related but isn't the second argument missing in `.replace(…)`

Comment: This is a missprint. Instead `.replace(...)` the same result with `toUpperCase()`

Comment: My first idea is probably not a good direction